# Use MGF's to show that $S-X \sim \chi^2$ with $n$ degrees of freedom

Tags: solution-verification, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that $X \sim \chi^2$ with $m$ degrees of freedom, $S=X+Y\sim \chi^2(m+n)$ and $X$ e $Y$  are independent use MGF's  to show  that $S-X \sim \chi^2$ with $n$ degrees of freedom this is my work
[image]

Comment: The third line is not correct, since $X$ and $S$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Proceed this way:

1. Start with the MGF of $S$.
2. Express the MGF of $S$ as the product of the MGFs of two RVs $X$ and $Y$
3. Given the distribution of $X$ pin down the MGF of $Y$.
4. Conclude that $Y$ has the desired distribution.